# on_disconnect isn't being triggered python

Tags: python, mqtt, paho

I've tried a number of iterations of this code.  This is the last attempt and I'm stumped.  It never sees the published message in addition to not getting the on disconnect.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt  #import the client1
import time

def on_message(client, userdata, message):
  print("received message =",str(message.payload.decode("utf-8")))

def on_disconnect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    client.connected_flag=False #set flag
    print("disconnected OK")

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    if rc==0:
        client.connected_flag=True #set flag
        print("connected OK")
        client.subscribe("Phone/announcet")#subscribe
        print("subscribed OK")
    else:
        print("Bad connection Returned code=",rc)

mqtt.Client.connected_flag=False#create flag in class
broker="192.168.1.71"
client = mqtt.Client()             #create new instance 
print("Connecting to broker ",broker)
client.username_pw_set(username="zzz",password="xxx")
while True:
    client.on_connect=on_connect  #bind call back function
    client.on_disconnect=on_disconnect
    client.connect(broker)      #connect to broker
    client.loop_start()
    while not client.connected_flag: #wait in loop
        print("In wait loop")
        time.sleep(1)
    print("in Main Loop")
    time.sleep(2)
    client.loop_stop()    #Stop loop 
    client.disconnect() # disconnect
    print("After disconnect")
```

Here is what the output looks like:

```
Connecting to broker  192.168.1.71
In wait loop
connected OK
subscribed OK
in Main Loop
After disconnect
in Main Loop
connected OK
subscribed OK
After disconnect
in Main Loop
connected OK
subscribed OK
After disconnect
```

Thanks,
Jim

Comment: Assuming no other issues, this will only connect for 2 seconds which is a pretty small window to receive any messages in.

Comment: This was just a test to see if I can get it working.  It should reconnect quite quickly.  Just for kicks I did increase it to 20 seconds and tested.  It still didn't receive the message....  My main concern is that the on_disconnect doesn't seem to be working so my logic for reconnecting isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you are not setting the `on_message` callback on the client, this is why you are getting no messages.

Second there is no benefit setting the callbacks inside the loop, they are better moved outside the main loop.

Third you are stopping the loop before calling disconnect, since all the callbacks run on the client event loop the `on_disconnect` will never get called. You also have an extra argument in the `on_disconnect`, there should be no `flags`.

I'm also not sure your `connected_flag` will ever work, it should be moved to a global variable

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt  #import the client1
import time

connected_flag=False

def on_message(client, userdata, message):
    print("received message =",str(message.payload.decode("utf-8")))

def on_disconnect(client, userdata, rc):
    global connected_flag 
    connected_flag=False #set flag
    print("disconnected OK")

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    global connected_flag
    if rc==0:
        connected_flag=True #set flag
        print("connected OK")
        client.subscribe("Phone/announcet") #subscribe
        print("subscribed OK")
    else:
        print("Bad connection Returned code=",rc)

broker="192.168.1.71"
client = mqtt.Client()             #create new instance 
print("Connecting to broker ",broker)
client.username_pw_set(username="zzz",password="xxx")
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message
client.on_disconnect = on_disconnect

while True:
    client.connect(broker)      #connect to broker
    client.loop_start()
    while not connected_flag: #wait in loop
        print("In wait loop")
        time.sleep(1)
    print("in Main Loop")
    time.sleep(3)
    print(connected_flag)
    client.disconnect() # disconnect
    print("After disconnect")
    print(connected_flag)
    client.loop_stop()
```

Comment: I changed the client.connected_flag variables to connected_flag to make it work. I edited it so there would be a working version of the code.  I don't know if that's proper etiquette.  I'm   sorry if that was improper.

Comment: Thank you very much.  The documentation is sometimes a bit confusing and I'm a fairly new python programmer.  Regards, Jim